# MySQL threads_connected and SHOW PROCESSLIST don't match

Tags: mysql

We're using MySQL in a shared environment and have periodically experienced "too many connections" problems.  As I try to diagnose this, everyone seems to recommend `SHOW PROCESSLIST` or checking the 'Threads_connected' variable in the `SHOW STATUS` output.  All of the references I've found imply that both of these display equivalent information, ie that 'threads_connected' should match the number of entries returned by `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, but in all my tests `SHOW PROCESSLIST` only shows one entry while 'threads_connected' fluctuates between 3 and 10.

My hunch is that `SHOW PROCESSLIST` is only displaying my connections while 'threads_connected' is showing a thread count for all users, but I haven't been able to find anything that positively states this.  So what's the deal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the doc:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-processlist.html

and in particular:

"
If you have the PROCESS privilege, you can see all threads. Otherwise, you can see only your own threads (that is, threads associated with the MySQL account that you are using)
"